# How to use getServerSideProps when it required argument is from Page in Nextjs

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, getserversideprops

I am calling the internal API route by passing the `searchParams` to search the database (api/model/route.js):

```js
import { connectToDB } from "@/app/utils/database";
import Events from "@/models/events";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export const GET = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  await connectToDB();
  const matchString: String = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("data") || "[]"
  const events: any = {};
  const promises = matchString.split(",").map(async (match: string) => {
    try {
      events[match] = await Events.find({ name: match }).then((res) => res[0]);
    } catch (error) {
      events[match] = error;
      console.log("model/route.js error")
    }
  })

  await Promise.all(promises)
  return new Response(JSON.stringify(events), { status: 200 });
};
```

I am trying to use `GetServerSideProps` to do:

```js
await fetch("/api/model?data=" + searchParams.data)
```

However, `searchParams` is not at `getServerSideProps`, instead it's inside the Page function:

```js
export default async function Page({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: SearchParams;
}) {
  const selectedMatch = searchParams.data || "[]";
...
```

so how can I fetch the database at request time? I want to base on the result to initialise my `useState` object.